# (JavaScript noob question) devide js from html with third party lib import

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a noob to `js`, but a js lib is quite helpful to my usecase, and I wish to devide the it's demo `js` code from html for a better extending, with third party lib import. As lack of experience, I cannot find any clue... can I get some advice?

I modified the official [demo](https://github.com/vasturiano/3d-force-graph/blob/master/example/bloom-effect/index.html)

to the following `index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style> body { margin: 0; } </style>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.150.1/build/three.js"></script>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/3d-force-graph@1.71.2/dist/3d-force-graph.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="3d-graph"></div>

  <script type="importmap">{ "imports": { "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.150.1/build/three.module.js" }}</script>
  <script type="module">
    import { UnrealBloomPass } from 'https://unpkg.com/three@0.150.1/examples/jsm/postprocessing/UnrealBloomPass.js';

    const gData = {
        nodes: [
            { id: "node1", name: "Node 1" },
            { id: "node2", name: "Node 2" },
            { id: "node3", name: "Node 3" },
        ],
        links: [
            { id: "link1", name: "link 1", source: "node1", target: "node2" },
            { id: "link2", name: "link 2", source: "node2", target: "node3" },
            { id: "link3", name: "link 3", source: "node3", target: "node1" },
        ]}

    const Graph = ForceGraph3D()
      (document.getElementById('3d-graph'))
      .graphData(gData)

    const bloomPass = new UnrealBloomPass();
    bloomPass.strength = 3;
    bloomPass.radius = 1;
    bloomPass.threshold = 0.1;
    Graph.postProcessingComposer().addPass(bloomPass);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

the above `index.html` could work directly in browser. but when i devide it to `index2.js` and `index2.html`, I don't know how to make it works, below is one of my attempts:

`index2.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style> body { margin: 0; } </style>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.150.1/build/three.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/3d-force-graph@1.71.2/dist/3d-force-graph.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="3d-graph"></div>

  <script type="importmap"> { "imports": { "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.150.1/build/three.module.js" }} </script>
  <!-- <script type="module">
    import { UnrealBloomPass } from 'https://unpkg.com/three@0.150.1/examples/jsm/postprocessing/UnrealBloomPass.js';
  </script> -->
  <script src="./index2.js"> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and corresponding `index2.js`

```js
import { UnrealBloomPass } from 'https://unpkg.com/three@0.150.1/examples/jsm/postprocessing/UnrealBloomPass.js';

window.onload = function load() {
  const gData = {
        nodes: [
            { id: "node1", name: "Node 1" },
            { id: "node2", name: "Node 2" },
            { id: "node3", name: "Node 3" },
        ],
        links: [
            { id: "link1", name: "link 1", source: "node1", target: "node2" },
            { id: "link2", name: "link 2", source: "node2", target: "node3" },
            { id: "link3", name: "link 3", source: "node3", target: "node1" },
        ]}

    const Graph = ForceGraph3D()
      (document.getElementById('3d-graph'))
      .graphData(gData)

    
    const bloomPass = new UnrealBloomPass();
    bloomPass.strength = 3;
    bloomPass.radius = 1;
    bloomPass.threshold = 0.1;
    Graph.postProcessingComposer().addPass(bloomPass);
}
```

thanks for any advice

Comment: You need `type="module"`: `<script type="module" src="./index2.js"> </script>`

Comment: @Unmitigated, thanks for advice, do you mean just modify the correspodings of `index2.html` to `<script type="module" src="./index2.js"> </script>`? I tried but still no work. And if commentout the `import` part at the beginning of `index2.js` , I got error like `Uncaught ReferenceError: UnrealBloomPass is not defined` , do I miss something else?

Comment: Are you testing locally? Are you using a HTTP server or just local files?

Comment: just local files :)